# RStudio changes branch of git repository into detached mode

Tags: git, rstudio

I have got several R projects which use git as scm and when switching branches through the gui that RStudio provides, it leaves me into detached mode, i.e, the tip of the checked out branch is not associated with none of the existing branches.

[image]

Any ideas why that happens and how to solve within the RStudio?
(I've searched and apparently `git checkout <branch>` leaves you again into the branch I originally wanted to checkout).